# Find the first time a value increased 1.85 - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing some code to look for the minimum value in a rolling 7 day window.

First I am finding the minimum value for each day and inserting into a temp table #minimumvalue
This is to take into account days where there are multiple values.

I am finding the rolling_min value by using `min(Value) over(partition by ID order by Date_Value rows between 6 preceding and current row` and this is what I get

```
ID | Date_Value |       Value |  rolling_min
1234  1-1-2018 12:15 pm  2.95   1.54    
1234 1-1-2018 3:30 pm    1.54   1.54    
1234 1-2-2018 10:45 am   1.57   1.54    
1234 1-3-2018 2:15 pm    2.02   1.54    
1234 1-4-2018 4:00 pm    2.80   1.54    
1234 1-5-2018            NULL   1.54    
1234 1-6-2018            NULL   1.54    
1234 1-7-2018            NULL   1.56    
1234 1-8-2018            NULL   1.57
```

the first 2 rows take place on the same day so the rolling_min starts out with 1.54. Really it should start out at 2.95 since that is the current minimum.

From there I want to find the first instance that the minimum had *Increased* by 1.85. 
I tried a case statement `CASE WHEN Value >= 1.85 * MIN(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date_Value ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0
END AS Increase YN`

This is the result

```
ID | Date_Value |       Value |  rolling_min |  Increase YN
1234  1-1-2018 12:15 pm  2.95   1.54             1
1234 1-1-2018 3:30 pm    1.54   1.54             0
1234 1-2-2018 10:45 am   1.57   1.54             0
1234 1-3-2018 2:15 pm    2.02   1.54             0
1234 1-4-2018 4:00 pm    2.80   1.54             1
1234 1-5-2018            NULL   1.54             0
1234 1-6-2018            NULL   1.54             0
1234 1-7-2018            NULL   1.57             0
1234 1-8-2018            NULL   1.57             0
```

The first row displays 1 since it is 1.85 * the min of 1.54 but that 1.54 comes after so that's not really what I want. how could I avoid that and just return a 1 where it increased?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please provide data sample and your full current query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to find the first time when any data value goes 85% above the minimum for the last 6 days.  I hope that is right.

This is my code:

```
create table data
(ID int not null,
Date_Value datetime not null,
Value decimal(5,2)
)
go
truncate table data
go
insert into data 
select 1234,  '2018-01-01 12:15:00',  2.95
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-01 12:15:00',  1.54
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-02 10:45:00',  1.57
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-03 14:15:00',  2.02
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-04 16:00:00',  2.80
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-05',  null
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-06',  null
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-07',  null
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-08',  null
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-09 09:00:00',  3.4
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-09 10:00:00',  5.4
union all select 1234,  '2018-01-09 11:00:00',  8.4
go
insert into data 
select 9999,  '2018-01-01 12:15:00',  2.95
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-01 12:15:00',  1.54
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-02 10:45:00',  1.57
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-03 14:15:00',  2.02
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-04 16:00:00',  2.80
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-05',  null
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-06',  null
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-07',  null
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-08',  null
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-09 09:00:00',  3.4
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-09 10:00:00',  5.4
union all select 9999,  '2018-01-09 11:00:00',  8.4
go

;with ByDayMin as 
(
    select ID, Date_Value = cast(Date_Value as date), Value=min(Value)
    from data
    group by ID, cast(Date_Value as date) 

),
IncBig as (
select ID, Date_Value,
        Value,
        sixDayMin =  MIN(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date_Value ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
from ByDayMin

),Calcs as
(
    select d.*,
        i.SixDayMin,
        ValueIncreaseRatioLast6Days = d.Value / SixDayMin,
        Prior =   LAG(d.Date_Value, 1,null) OVER(PARTITION BY d.ID ORDER BY d.Date_Value)

from data d
join ByDayMin b
on b.ID = d.ID
    and b.Date_Value = cast(d.Date_Value as date) 
join IncBig i
on i.ID = d.ID
    and i.Date_Value = b.Date_Value

)

select c.ID, c.Date_Value, c.Value, c.SixDayMin, ValueIncreaseRatioLast6Days, 
        Increase_YN=case when c.ValueIncreaseRatioLast6Days >= 1.85
                            and not exists (select 1 from Calcs c2 
                                            where c2.ID = c.ID 
                                                and c2.ValueIncreaseRatioLast6Days >= 1.85
                                                and c2.Date_Value < c.Date_Value
                                                and Prior is not Null
                                            )
                            and Prior is not Null
                        then 1
                        else 0
                    end
    from Calcs c

order by c.ID, c.Date_Value
```

[image: Results]

Comment: just did a quick test and this seems to work! my code looked pretty similar to how you were doing it until that last case statement. I will do some further testing but this looks promising. thank you so much! I will report back once I complete further testing.

Comment: Just finished some testing and it works for what I need. Again thanks! saved me further headache over this :)